# Problem with getting width and height after the component is loaded into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could you give me solution how to read the dimension of the newly loaded html component?

I have a webpage which has a JavaScript content loader class to load the HTML component via AJAX, and add it in the designated area, but the problem is once the component is loaded and replaced in the HTML page, the variables `clientWidth`, and `clientHeight` seemed not to work properly. According to the inspect element tool on Google Chrome, suppose I have `<div>ABCD</div>` which has the dimension of 250x50 px. By accessing variable `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`, it supposed to return me 250px, and 50px respectively, but it didn't.

You can get the correct dimension once after the browser window has been resized, why can't we get the correct dimension right after the component is firstly loaded?

I have also have the CSS style to control the width and height of the loaded component. The structure of the web page is shown below.

```html
<html>
   *scripts content loader (AJAX)
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxloader.js"></script>
  <div id="content_wrapper">
       the AJAX content loader loads the HTML component and place it here, 
       including the CSS source file. So, after it loads, it looks like this...
    <div id="menu_bar">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/css/style1.css"/>
      
       // Chrome Inspect element tool returns the dimension of 250px by 50px
       <div>ABCD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <script>
      Callback function from the AJAX loader, fires the event after  the content has been 
      successfully loaded, and placed to the HTML page.
      function(){
        // The clientWidth and clientHeight could not work properly here, even the HTML element 
        // has already been replaced....
      }
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be sure based on what you're showing us but I'm guessing that you're reading width and height of your element right after it has been inserted. You need to wait that the element has been render. A `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` should do the trick.

```js
// insert you're element's content
setTimeout(_ => {
    // read width and height
});
```

Comment: Thanks. that actually solved the problem with the delay of 500 milliseconds, but would it be better to check whether if the content has been rendered before firing up the JS code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice at first that inside the code you're adding using AJAX there is a `link` tag (I'm not sure this is a very good practice but this is not the point). This means once your code is injected in the DOM, the browser needs to request the CSS, and render it. This is why setTimeout isn't working

Comment: Now I'm ended up using the delay of 100 millisecond, it worked fine, but not so sure if the trouble will exist if there're more elements to be rendered in the future.

Comment: I don't believe this is a good idea, if for some reason downloading the css file takes longer 100ms could not be enought. can the CSS be added to the header ?

Comment: Yes, the CSS and be added to the head (it will solve all the delay problems), but according the the plan, the HTML and CSS has to be obtained from the server, so I had to make it this way.